# QGIS How to change display name of layer in legend using layer metadata?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, legend

In the ***Layout Manager***, I want to change for a selection of layers the *name displayed in legend* without changing the layer names.

I am using QGIS 3.16

I am getting the legend entry names from the layer metadata (in my case the 'Title' data)

[image: Properties Menu]

This is what I have tested so far:

I went to the legend Items Menu

[image: Legend Item]

Edit icon

[image: Label Menu]

and I am trying to build an expression to display the title metadata

Expressions tested:

```
attribute('title')
-->Preview  No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression.

display_expression(@layer,'title')
--> Preview: Expression invalid
```

...

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to work:

`layer_property( @layer,'title')`